# How can I fix "Missing \endcsname inserted." in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I'm very new to tikz and I'm trying to create a pattern using a for loop.

```
\foreach \k in {60,120,180,240,300}
        \filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=anglecolor] (0,0) -- ({\k - 60}:0.35) arc [start angle=\k-60, end angle=\k, radius=0.35];
        \draw (\k - 30:2.2mm) node[anglecolor] {$\theta_r$};
        \draw[very thick, color=tancolor] (0,0) -- (\k:1);
```

Unfortulately, I get an error saying `Missing \endcsname inserted.` on the third line. I am using lualatex and I know that all my custom variables (anglecolor, tancolor) are properly defined. How can I fix this error?

Comment: compare `({\k - 60}:0.35)` with `(\k - 30:2.2mm)` should resolve the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't actually solve the issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use curly braces `{}` to wrap the loop body.

```
\foreach \k in {60,120,180,240,300}
        {\filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=anglecolor] (0,0) -- ({\k - 60}:0.35) arc [start angle=\k-60, end angle=\k, radius=0.35];
        \draw (\k - 30:2.2mm) node[anglecolor] {$\theta_r$};
        \draw[very thick, color=tancolor] (0,0) -- (\k:1);}
```

Comment: Yep, that worked! It's kinda fascinating how I've read a few guides that don't tell you specifically to wrap loops in curly braces. Thanks!